# Only added 1 line of code at the top

Tags: javascript, meteor

I don't know what I have to do to make it work here is the code:

```
Songs = new Mongo.Collections("songs");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
     // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
   // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

And here is the error:
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at newapp.js:1:9

All I did was add 1 line. Also how would I Run the appropriate Javascript code in the browser Javascript console to insert an item into the Songs collection.
I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Mongo.Collection` instead of `Mongo.Collections`. `s` at the end is not necessary.